# Htaccess - 301 redirect with analytics campaign parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, google-analytics, http-status-code-301

I have multiple domains directed to folder with .htaccess
my htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain-2.com
rewriteRule ^(.*) https://domain-1.com/?utm_source=redirects&utm_medium=domain-2.com&utm_campaign=301 [R=301,L]

rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain-3.com
rewriteRule ^(.*) https://domain-1.com/?utm_source=redirects&utm_medium=domain-3.com&utm_campaign=301 [R=301,L]
```

And I want do this more effective and elegantly - all domains are redirected to **domain-1.com**

Exist any way how use {HTTP_HOST} or something similar at URL parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domain-1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain-1.com/?utm_source=redirects&utm_medium=%{HTTP_HOST}&utm_campaign=301 [R=301,L]
```